# Permit sign with Web3.js fails

Tags: web3js, permit

I am trying to sign a message with Metamask to execute an ERC-20 permit for the user. I manage to generate the signature but the transaction to permit fails (I am probably not generating the signature successfully). This is the code I have:

```
const chainId = 137;

const domain = {
    name: '',
    version: '1',
    verifyingContract: usdcContractAddress,
    chainId,
};

const EIP712Domain = [
    { name: 'name', type: 'string' },
    { name: 'version', type: 'string' },
    { name: 'verifyingContract', type: 'address' },
    { name: 'chainId', type: 'uint256' },
];

const permit = {
    owner: fromAccount,
    spender: spenderContractAddress, 
    value: total, 
    nonce: await getUserNonce(),
    deadline: deadline, 
};

const Permit = [
    { name: 'owner', type: 'address' },
    { name: 'spender', type: 'address' },
    { name: 'value', type: 'uint256' },
    { name: 'nonce', type: 'uint256' },
    { name: 'deadline', type: 'uint256' },
];

const splitSig = (sig) => {
    const pureSig = sig.replace('0x', '');

    const _r = pureSig.slice(0, 64);
    const _s = pureSig.slice(64, 128);
    const _v = pureSig.slice(128);

    return { _r, _s, _v };
};

let sign;
let r;
let s;
let v;

const msgParams = {
    types: {
        EIP712Domain: EIP712Domain,
        Permit: Permit,
    },
    primaryType: 'Permit',
    domain,
    message: permit,
};

try {
    sign = await ethereum.request({
        method: 'eth_signTypedData_v4',
        params: [fromAccount, JSON.stringify(msgParams)],
    });

    const { _r, _s, _v } = splitSig(sign);

    r = `0x${_r}`;
    s = `0x${_s}`;
    v = parseInt(`0x${_v}`, 16);

    usdcInstance.methods.permit(fromAccount, spenderContractAddress, hexAmount, deadline, v, r, s).send({from:fromAccount})

} catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
}
```